# KQL make-series operator turns *some* averages of reals into a string

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am running the following query :

```
let data=datatable(timestamp: datetime, metric: real)
[
  datetime(2020-01-01 00:00:00), 50.3, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 00:10:00), 50.4, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 00:20:00), 50.5, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 00:30:00), 50.6, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 00:40:00), 50.7, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 00:50:00), 50.8, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 01:00:00), 50.9, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 01:10:00), 50.01, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 01:20:00), 50.08, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 01:30:00), 50.13, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 01:40:00), 50.65, 
  datetime(2020-01-01 01:50:00), 50.99 
];
data 
| make-series avg(metric) on timestamp step 15m;
```

Given that `metric` is of type `real`, I am expecting an array with only reals. However, I am getting the following result:

```
"avg_metric": [
    "50.349999999999994",
    50.5,
    "50.650000000000006",
    50.8,
    50.455,
    50.08,
    50.39,
    50.99
]
```

As can be seen, *some* values are reals, but also *some* values are strings! The expected behaviour would, of course, be that there are only reals in this list.

Why does Kusto/KQL behave in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted your example query, it doesn't reproduce (see screenshot below). Please explain how to reproduce. thanks

[image: query result]

Comment: Hi Adi E, thanks for taking the effort. I am using the Query Editor in Azure Data Explorer:

Comment: Hi Adi E, thanks for taking the effort! 

I am using the Query Editor in Azure Data Explorer. I see you are using the Kusto desktop client, and the bug does not show up there indeed, which I believe is even more weird! Will have to try this from code, and see what happens.